# Symfony 2 : difference between session and storage?

Tags: session, symfony

Can anyone explain to me the difference(s) between "session" and "storage" in Symfony 2 ?

I'm using PdoSessionStorage and I can't seen any relation between :

- Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session
- Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\PdoSessionStorage

... and both of these classes seem to be instanciated !

Answer (score 1):

One represents the session, the other the way the session is stored. PdoSessionStorage will handle storage through PDO on a database. It's a way of decoupling the actualy concept and content of the session from the storage of it, since it could be stored in different ways.

Why is that of your concern?

Also Session handling seems to have been refactored, I take it you're not using the latest version of symfony. But in any case, you shouldn't worry about these classes.

Comment: I'm using SF 2.0. But anyway, I don't understand how SF works with these 2 classes. I tried something : I disabled manually the "read" and "write" functions in PdoSessionStorage (for testing purpose only). Thus, I should not be able to access a restricted page because SF cannot read anymore my session datas. But even if I get correctly redirected to the login page, the HTTP response of this request (seen in Firebug) shows me the full HTML content of this restricted page. This is what I dont understand.

Comment: I think that may be quite a complicated thing of debugging what you're doing. May I suggest you take a different approach than editing classes inside Symfony, it seems to be confusing you rather than helping you. Disabling the session storage doesn't seem to be the more straightforward way to put or remove an access barrier at all, there's probably many ways at higher level of abstraction which are way easier to follow, and that includes code you actually wrote yourself.